# Android Back button with Fragment Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi guys i am developing an application with Extending `fragment` activity,here is my problem when i have used the normal activity is i have used below method.

```
onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, newKeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

- For activity what i need to do?

How can i achieve this goal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this link to help. Sorry that its old, but it kept coming up on the google.

[Fragment: which callback invoked when press back button & customize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703498/fragment-which-callback-invoked-when-press-back-button-customize-it/10100254#10100254)

Setup the callback in the activity. Then the fragment doesnt need an @Overrride.

note this will work for the back button, as well as onKeyDown.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented `onBackPressed` in my `(Fragment)Activity` and simply forwarded an appropriate message to the relevant fragment.

Furthermore can't you implement your `onKeyDown` event in your parent activity and do what you need to do which may be passing messages to your fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try below code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
              Intent i1 = new Intent(Activity1.class, Activity2.class);
              startActivity(i1);
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: sry i don't want to use, i am having to many back buttons. before that i have used like this.                              onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));