# Fragment: which callback invoked when press back button & customize it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I have a fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
     ...
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(...){...}    
     ...
}
```

I instantiate it:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
```

I use the above fragment to replace the current fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

// replace fragment
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, myFragment, "myTag");

// NOTE: I did not add to back stack
```

Now, `myFragment` is showing on the screen. NOTE: I did not add `myFragment` to **back stack**.

**My two questions:**

**1.** If now, I press mobile phone **back** button, which fragment's life cycle callback will be invoked??

**2.** How can I customize the **back button** click listener in `MyFragment` class? (please do not suggest me to do `myFragment.getView().setOnclickListener`, but do it in `MyFragment` class)

Answer (score 23):

Question 1: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle:

> > "As a fragment is no longer being used, it goes through a reverse series of callbacks:
> >
> > onPause() - fragment is no longer interacting with the user either because its activity is being paused or a fragment operation is
> >     modifying it in the activity.
> >
> > onStop() - fragment is no longer visible to the user either because its activity is being stopped or a fragment operation is modifying it
> >     in the activity.
> >
> > onDestroyView() - allows the fragment to clean up resources associated with its View.
> >
> > onDestroy() - called to do final cleanup of the fragment's state.
> >
> > onDetach() - called immediately prior to the fragment no longer being associated with its activity."

Question 2:  If you must know that it was the back button ***specifically*** that is triggering the callbacks, You can capture the back button press in your Fragment's Activity and use your own method to handle it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    //...
    //Defined in Activity class, so override
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        myFragment.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    //Your created method
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //Handle any cleanup you don't always want done in the normal lifecycle
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be used only for cleanup. I think that Mar was to prevent swap fragment from backstack if use press the back button.

Comment: In my case, `onBackPressed()` was not getting called. I fixed it by giving focus to the fragment view by getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus(); in onResume().

Answer (score 2):

[androidx.activity 1.0.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-nov-activity) is released and introduces `ComponentActivity`, a new base class of the existing `FragmentActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`.

You can now register an `OnBackPressedCallback` via `addOnBackPressedCallback` to receive `onBackPressed`() callbacks without needing to override the method in your activity.

Comment: can you show some specific code (and where it goes) for addOnBackPressedCallback ?